# addEventListener only to the direct children

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add an **event** on all the children of `ul`. (In this case `li` elements)

The problem is that it adds an event to its children as well (`a` elements).

```js
let myElements = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');

for (let i = 0; i < myElements.length; i ++ ) {
    myElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        console.log('Event !!!')

    });

}
```

```css
li {
        background: rgb(226, 226, 226);
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px;
    }

    a {
        background: rgb(255, 222, 219);
        border: 1px solid rgb(211, 65, 65);
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <a href="#">6</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Notice in the console, when the mouse moves on element 'a'.

Comment: mouseover event work on the element and its children

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`.

`mouseenter` only triggers when the mouse enters the element on which it is set.

`mouseover` triggers when the mouse enters the element or any of its children.

https://thisthat.dev/mouseenter-vs-mouseover/